# problem with applet database access

Tags: java, database, applet

the applet(which make connection to access database) i developed is working fine in applet viewer, but when embedded in an html file, it cannot access the database. how can i rectify it?

Comment: Are you using localhost or 127.0.0.1 in your connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applets respect same origin policy. It cannot connect to any other sever other than where it is hosted. You database and your webserver needs to be on same ip.

Comment: It seems as though the JRE does not consider it to be the same **site** though.  One typical case is where a non-relative URL is used to connect to the DB.  E.G. A page at D:where/my/server/is/WEB-INF/applet/db-applet.html could not connect to http://127.0.0.1:8080/db.  The applet would need to come from http://127.0.0.1:8080/applet/db-applet.html to make that work in a sand-box.

Answer (score 1):

An applet lives in a security sandbox. In order for you to do file io, your applet jar(s) need to be signed.

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/85application/jar/sign.html